# Determine if a set of equations has unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Determine if the following set of equations has unique solution of the
>   form $g(z)=(x,y)$ in the neighbourhood of the origin. $$\begin{cases}
>  xyz+\sin(xyz)=0 \\ x+y+z=0  \end{cases}$$

The answer is negative. In fact, there exists infinitely many solutions in the neighbourhood of the origin.

Let $F:ℝ^3\rightarrow ℝ^2, F(x,y,z)=(xyz+\sin(xyz),x+y+z).$ If we consider the function $F$, we notice that $F(\epsilon,-\epsilon,0)=(0,0)$ $∀\epsilon>0$.
Because we can choose $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small,  $\nexists{R>0}$ such that n-hood of the origin $B(0,R)$ would contain a unique solution $(x,y,z)=(g(z),z)$ such that $F(x,y,z)=0$. Thus the set of equations doesn't have a unique solution in **any** n-hood of the origin. Is this correct? Are there alternative methods?

Comment: This looks like an implicit function question. Are you sure that the text isn't asking if there is a unique _function_ $g(z)=(x, y)$ such that for all $z$ near the origin, $(g(z), z)$ satisfies the equations? If instead the text is actually asking for solutions to the system, then your answer is correct.

Comment: That could actually be the case, since currently we are dealing with the implicit function theorem. How should the answer be modified? I have checked that the Jacobian at the origin is not surjective, thus the implicit function theorem is inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. However, the answer becomes obvious if you try to plot (or even just imagine) the graph of the zeroes of the system.

First, notice that the system is perfectly symmetrical in its variables: that is, rearranging $x, y$ and $z$ does not change the equations.

Your argument pretty much shows that the graph of the zeroes of the system, while in a neighborhood of $(0, 0, 0)$, contains a segment of the line $(-t, t, 0)$.

However, by symmetry, it must also contain a segment of the line $(t, -t, 0)$, so any function $g(z)$ as required by the text would need to hold two different $(x, y)$ values near $z=0$, and as such, cannot exist.

Note that, again by symmetry, the same argument applies for any $f(x)$ and $h(y)$ you could try to find, confirming the validity of Dini's theorem.

Comment: I have not heard of Dini's theorem. is it essential in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the implicit function theorem. Here in Italy it is known as Dini's theorem, probably because of national pride ;)

Comment: Now I am just thinking how to wrap it up.